# Setup Gist extension for VS Code

Tags: github, visual-studio-code, gist

I'm trying to use the [Gist](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kenhowardpdx.vscode-gist) extension for VS Code.

I did the following steps:

- Install extension
- `GIST: select profile`
- `Create New Profile` -> `Github.com (common)`
- On Github, I created a new access token, then I copied the token and I pasted it on VS Code

When I do `GIST: open gist` I have no gist in the list, but on Github I have 3 secret gists.

Why? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1st**, make sure that when you created the access token on Github, you enabled the **gist** access:

https://github.com/settings/tokens/new:
[image]

(If you haven't created an access token or you want to make sure you created it properly, see [Github's docs on Creating a personal access token](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token)).

The extension does not raise an error if the token you created and pasted does not have **gist** access, but when you do "**GIST: Open Gist**", the list will show up as empty.

**2nd**, the extension seems to only support **owned** gists, meaning gists you created under the same account as the access token. It does not include **starred** or favorited ones. You can check by going to your [https://gist.github.com/[username]](https://gist.github.com/%5Busername%5D), and selecting the **All gists** tab. Only those under that tab will be fetched by the VS Code extension.

There was an issue ["Feature - Open Starred Gists"](https://github.com/kenhowardpdx/vscode-gist/issues/61) and a PR ["feat: adds open favorite"](https://github.com/kenhowardpdx/vscode-gist/pull/62) opened by the author himself, but as of 3.0.3 that I am using now, my favorited/starred gists still don't show up.